# Getting http error 415 - sending int from HttpClient to a FromBody parameter

Tags: asp.net-core

```
(await _client.PutAsync("foo", new StringContent(5.ToString()))).EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```

```
public async Task Put([FromBody]int bar)
```

I get HTTP error 415 - "Unsupported Media Type"

Answer (score 1):

According to the error message, the 415 means the request format is mot match the api required format.

Since you use Frombody attribute, you should use the application/json as the request body format.

I suggest you could try to use below codes to send the put request with the request body 5.

Client Codes：

```
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
    public HomeController( IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
   
        _httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
        _httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:7264/");
    }

    public IActionResult Privacy()
    {

        // Serialize the integer into JSON
        string jsonContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(5);

        // Create a StringContent object with JSON content and specify the media type
        var content = new StringContent(jsonContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        // Send the HTTP PUT request with the JSON content and Content-Type header
        var response = _httpClient.PutAsync("WeatherForecast", content);

        return View();
    }
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to the standards on [HTTP response status codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/415)

> The HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type client error response code indicates that the server refuses to accept the request because the payload format is in an unsupported format

In your case, you are sending `StringContent(5.ToString())`, which will be a string with media type `text\plain`.
Your body however is accepting an `int` value, not a string.

If both client and server are in your control, you can decide on a format to use but have to stick to it on both sides.

Comment: It feels like 90% of programming problems are datatype issues.

Comment: That was one of my first thoughts, though I was pretty certain it should accept it as a string as everything is going to be a string and Put, Post from HttpClient only allow you to send strings.  Also from GET variables it does accept it as a int.  Either way, string also gives the same error.

Comment: @Bluebaron did you try changing the content type that your client sends? For example via "new StringContent(<your_string>, UnicodeEncoding.UTF8, "application/json");"

Comment: @jraufeisen 400 bad request

Comment: I tried to do what you just did in a way that's worked before in our project on non-primitive types, and it didn't work.  So I'm thinking the primitive type matters.